# How to query svg elements with document.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, xpath, svg

I have a document with a `div` element, which contains a `svg` element.

When I query the `div` elements I get a return value showing even the `svg` child element.

```
$x('//div')
[<div class=​"schema">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"relations">​<svg class=​"relations">​…​</svg>​</div>​]
```

But when I query the `svg` element itself I get no result.

```
$x('//svg')
[]
```

And I have no idea why. I did this in Chromium 45.0.2454.85.

Can anybody explain what happens here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG elements are in the SVG namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, if you use the `evaluate` DOM method then you can pass in a namespace resolver as the third argument:

```js
function setFill(xpath, color) {
  var el = document.evaluate(xpath, document, function(prefix) { if (prefix === 'svg') { return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'; }}, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (el !== null) {
    el.setAttribute('fill', color);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="200" height="200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
  <input type="button" value="red" onclick="setFill('//svg:circle', 'red');">
</div>
```

I don't know whether the `$x` function in the developer tool allows something similar.

Comment: O I remember. I think once I had already the same problem in Java.